# Remove double quotes from bracelet in json_encode nested array php

Tags: php, json

I have array like this

```
datasets:[{"label":"admin ",  
"backgroundColor":"#FF6384",
"data":"[0,0,3,30,53,6,0,0,54,0,0,6]"},
{"label":"user1",
"backgroundColor":"#FF6384",
"data":"[0,20,0,3,0,0,5,20,30,0,5,0]"}],
```

I want to Remove double quotes from data array
And I want change to this

```
datasets:[{"label":"admin ",  
"backgroundColor":"#FF6384",
"data":[0,0,3,30,53,6,0,0,54,0,0,6]},
{"label":"user1",
"backgroundColor":"#FF6384",
"data":[0,20,0,3,0,0,5,20,30,0,5,0]}],
```

Comment: Can you please tell us why do you want to remove the quotes as it will break the json? I think you know you can access those values using **json_decode**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a RegEx too, but only editing on the `data` keys:

```
// Assuming your data string as $json
$json = preg_replace('/"data":"(\[[0-9,]*\])"/', '"data":$1', $json);

// Output to verify
echo '<pre>' . print_r(json_decode($json, true), true) . '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too much elegant but functionally

```
preg_replace("/\"(\[.*\])\"/", "$1", $Json);
```

`$1` is string that contain [something].